# Как задавать кнопке Click через свойства UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, события

Имеется UserControl в виде Grid`а с кнопкой внутри. До этого момента мне не требовалось менять click у кнопки, и я просто прописывал его явно при объявлении кнопки. Однако, теперь мне нужна возможность задавать кнопке разные хендлеры для click через свойство UserControl.
Что-то типа такого:

```
<local:AlternateResistorGrid ButtonClick="CurrentMethod"/>
```

Можно ли это реализовать?

Comment: надеюсь правильно понял, вот [статья](https://wpf-tutorial.com/ru/501/usercontrols-customcontrols/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-usercontrol/) , по идее тебе надо создать свойство в классе для события и потом передавать его при внедрении юзерконтрола

Comment: @Pekor, видел эту статью, но она не дала понять, как сделать свойство, которое принимало бы метод-обработчик. И как при этом прибиндить кнопке это свойство. Это я и пытаюсь выяснить